# printing foreign text for PHP on UBUNTU and CENTOS

Tags: php

I am using domdocuments and using things like $div->nodeValue to obtain certain info from a web page.

On my ubuntu machine when i do php crawl.php
everything is displayed properly in Chinese (the page is in UTF-8).

However on my CENTOS machine using the same code I get 
æ´å¤åå¸ when I print in the terminal.
and when I save it to the database, the characters are also messed up.

One thing I noticed is that when I do print $content, both systems display them properly.

Comment: I think this belongs on serverfault.com or superuser.com since it's probably more of a configuration thingy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a terminal encoding issue.